# How can I tell which HP printers have 64-bit drivers?

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, printer

I'm trying to put a shortlist of printers together for a client, but one of their outsourced IT department's rules is that the drivers need to be available in a 64-bit version. We really like HP printers, and would prefer to stick with that brand.

Is there a way to tell which drivers are 64-bit without downloading them all first?

Answer (score 0):

If you narrow the print device based on the features/functions needed you can easily see the drivers on teh download page.  They will be clearly identified as 64 Bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd hit shopping.hp.com and click "live assistance" on the left. Probably the fastest way to get a list.

You could also, as recommended [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895612), go through the add printer process on a computer running a 64-bit version of Windows, and view the list of HP printers with built-in drivers.

You'd think they'd have a nice list somewhere, though, wouldn't you?